Font showing in Pages but not in Font book (or other apps)
On my 13.0 Ventura Mac, in the Pages app I can see there is a "Times" and a "Times New Roman" font installed and I can use them :

When I look in the Font book, however, if I make a search with the "Times" keyword I only see the "Times New Roman" font :

How is that possible ? How can I find where the "Times" font file is located ? It is not in ~/Library/Fonts.

Over the years, Apple has removed a number of fonts from macOS. However, because many people have created any documents using these fonts, they are still available in documents that already use them.
Apple calls these fonts "document-supported".
https://support.apple.com/108939 (for Ventura . https://support.apple.com/en-us/103197)
"These fonts are only available to documents that already use the font, or to apps that request the font by name. Some are older fonts that were included with earlier versions of macOS or Apple apps."
Note that Pages does not show Times in my font menu.

